# Plone 4.3.7 zope user lost permissions in plone

Tags: ldap, plone, zope, plone-4.x

I have a Plone 4.3.7 installed using `UnifiedInstaller` with LDAP `plone.app.ldap-1.3.2-py2.7` a couple of yrs in each Plone Sites, I didn't nothing and now any user cannot create anything in Plone Site.

I reviewed all privilages for local zope users and LDAP users even so my output is `Insufficient Privileges`

[Update 1]

In `acl_users/portal_roler_manager` show the error `MultiplePrincipalError: Multiple groups or users exist with the name 'Administrators'. Remove one of the duplicate groups or users.`, but in acl_user don't have one or more users with this name_id.

Comment: perhaps, your ldap-groups have this entries.

Comment: I remove the product of LDAP, however the users in `zope/acl_users` don't have permission for creste  nothing.